# Minipage with four figures - avoiding too much whitespace

Tags: floats, minipage

I have hundreds of figures that I have arranged into 2x2 matrices using the `\minipage` environment like so:

```
\begin{figure}[ht] \label{ fig7} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_profile_0} 
    \caption{Initial condition} 
  \end{minipage} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_profile_Rup} 
    \caption{Rupture} 
  \end{minipage} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_dft_0_corner} 
    \caption{DFT, Initial condition} 
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_dft_corner_Rup} 
    \caption{DFT, rupture} 
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
```

I find that with this kind of an arrangement I have lots of white space after the figures. How should I ensure that I use all the "page real-estate" for my figures without too much white space?

I am really sorry that I can't seem to explain my problem any better.

[image]

### How to avoid spilling of images into following page?

As per the comments, when I use `\includegraphics[width=x\linewidth]` with `x>0.5`, my images spill into the following page. I would like my table and image to be in the same page and have the images leave little white space:

**Images moving to following page:**

[image]

**I would like this with lesser white space:**
[image]

**Minimum working example:**

```
\documentclass[draft,10pt]{article}

% \usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
% \usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{tabular}

\begin{document}
 MWE:
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
        a & 1 \\ 
    a & 1 \\ 
b & 1 \\ 
c & 1 \\ 
d & 1 \\ 
e & 1 \\ 
f & 1 \\ 
g & 1 \\ 
h & 1 \\ 
i & 1 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[h] \label{ fig7} \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.70\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_profile_0} \caption{Initial condition} \end{minipage} \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.70\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_profile_Rup} \caption{Rupture} \end{minipage} \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.70\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_dft_0_corner} \caption{DFT, Initial condition} \end{minipage}\hfill \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.70\linewidth]{/home/dnaneet/Research/Dissertation/wigner/Effect_of_domainSize_wavelength/G=0.333/dftdata/L_lambda_max_1wl_dft_corner_Rup} \caption{DFT, rupture} \end{minipage} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would still be useful to have a full document.   For example, there's nothing here to tell us what your page geometry is.

Comment: @A.Ellett A latex document?

Comment: [Just a MWE---to know what that is click on this link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/22413)

Comment: Also, without having a MWE, you might consider some of the question/answers on this site addressing [placement of floats and tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2282/22413).  You might also consider [this link on movement of floats](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats)

Comment: @A.Ellett Thank you for the suggestion! An MWE has been included.

Comment: I always get nervous when people start playing with layout of figures. Latex does a pretty good job and the 'lots of whitespace' you refer to, makes a page easy to read. Do you have a page limit that means you _need_ to do this? Alternatively, have you thought of increasing the size of your figures?

Comment: Your MWE seems to work fine.  Your table and figure are placed on the same page.  I suppose the problem could be text before and after your table and figure.  In the case, issuing `\pagebreak` before the table will force a page break and cause the table and figure to show up on the same page, but at the possible expense of a lot of empty whitespace on the preceding page.

Comment: @A.Ellett Excuse my english but I don't think I have reached you yet. Theres whitespace after the figures that I want to avoid. Is there something other than \textwidth  etc that I can do?

Comment: Placing `\centering` inside the `table` environment?

Answer (score 29):

You could try putting `\centering` in the `minipage`.  Adding some `\vspace` after the caption might be helpful too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
  \label{ fig7} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{Initial condition} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}%%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
    \caption{Rupture} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c} 
    \caption{DFT, Initial condition} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}%% 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{DFT, rupture} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an example of using `subcaptions` packages to get subfigures within a larger figure environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{Initial condition} 
    \label{fig7:a} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
    \caption{Rupture} 
    \label{fig7:b} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-c} 
    \caption{DFT, Initial condition} 
    \label{fig7:c} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{DFT, rupture} 
    \label{fig7:d} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \caption{Illustration of various images}
  \label{fig7} 
\end{figure}

The illustrations in figure~\ref{fig7}\ldots but in figure~\ref{fig7:d} you see\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there some way I could make the figures larger but ensuring that they don't overflow into the next page? Some sort of "float" related trick?

Comment: @drN You can adjust the width in the argument to `\includegraphics`.  Currently you have it set to `0.5\linewidth` which is actually `0.25\textwidth` since `\linewidth` is relative to currently effective `\linewidth` set by the `minipage`.

Comment: Your code has a spurious blank space; also, there's a `\label` without `\caption`.

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes. But when I change `0.5 \linewidth` to a larger multiple, my figures flow into the next page.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you, I hadn't noticed the `\label`.

Comment: @drN To more fully understand how large you can make this images, it would be helpful to have a full working example that illustrates how the figure gets moved with larger figures.

Comment: @drN Also, as GonzaloMedina points out, the `\label` as you placed it will not be effective.  You'll either want to place a `\label` with each caption.  Or if you just want to reference the group, you might want to consider using `subfigure`s and `subcaption`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I never realized that! Thank you!

Comment: @A.Ellett Just included an example of what I mean by "spilling of images into the following page"

Comment: What is the purpose of the `%%` ?

Comment: @shadowhorst A `%` at the end of the line prevents unintended whitespace from creeping in.  A single `%` would have sufficed.  I've somehow gotten into the habit of doubling these because of how they appear in my editor and it also makes them a bit more easy to spot (particularly when it looks like whitespace has crept in where I don't want it and I'm trying to debug things).

Comment: @A.Ellett is there a way to change the labels from (a), (b),... to (i), (ii),...? Thanks!

Comment: @A.Ellett thoughts on the previous comment?

Comment: @A.Ellett how about now?

Comment: @Nitin I really haven't had time in my schedule to re-examine this.  Perhaps you should post it as a question if you feel you need an answer to this soon.

Comment: How to ensure that all four images are in the centre? it's working but all four images are towards the right side compare than left

Answer (score 0):

```
\frame{\frametitle{Methodology [Contd.]}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
     \begin{center}
%
        \subfigure{%
            \label{fig:first}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img3-fig1.png}
        }%
        \subfigure{%
           \label{fig:second}
           \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img3-fig2.png}
        }\\ %  ------- End of the first row ----------------------%
        \subfigure{%
            \label{fig:third}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img3-fig3.png}
        }%
        \subfigure{%
            \label{fig:fourth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img3-fig4.png}
        }%
%
    \end{center}
    \caption{%
        The distribution of IQ Score obtained for various students in context of different test given by an individual student.
     }%
   \label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your code snippet is not very useful, because it does not neither compile not show or explain, which packages are needed. Moreover it seems, you are using a completely different class. Note also, that the already existing answer already shows a suggestion in using sub-figures (with an environment provided by package `subcaption` instead of a command, provided by an unknown package or class). So can please explain the code you are showing and extend the code to a working example?