# Enumerate graphs with minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, enumerate, minipage

I'd like to enumerate my graphs the way it is in the picture attached, but i just can't figure out how to get the numbers at the same place for each graph. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Have a look at the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Also please show us what you got so far by adding a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minipage with four figures - avoiding too much whitespace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126818/minipage-with-four-figures-avoiding-too-much-whitespace)

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

with use of `floatrow` and `subfig` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}

%\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
% Verweise werden im PDF zu Hyperlinks
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{figure}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
    \centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:a}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:b}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:c}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:d}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:e}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:f}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:g}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:h}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user1, any news?