# figures in a grid with multiple line of texts

Tags: subfloats, includegraphics

[image]

How can I put insert figures in a grid? Each figures will have 4 captions. I tried using subfloat but it doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}[ht] \label{ fig7} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth,valign=c]{1.jpg} 
\caption{The first caption}
\caption{The second caption}
\caption{The third caption}
\caption{The fourth caption}
  \end{minipage} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth,valign=c]{2.jpg} 
\caption{The first caption}
\caption{The second caption}
\caption{The third caption}
\caption{The fourth caption}
  \end{minipage} 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth,valign=c]{2.jpg} 
\caption{The first caption}
\caption{The second caption}
\caption{The third caption}
\caption{The fourth caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth,valign=c]{3.jpg} 
\caption{The first caption}
\caption{The second caption}
\caption{The third caption}
\caption{The fourth caption}
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You could see here, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126818/minipage-with-four-figures-avoiding-too-much-whitespace or here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162824/vertical-spacing-between-subfloat

Comment: one figure with four captions? please, show a sketch of how this should look like.

Comment: @Zarko, added. sorry about the orientation.

Comment: and where are captions? how they are numbered? and really each image has four caption? i never seen something like this demand ... (to my opinion, it does not make sense)

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks very much but is there any option to have multiple caption for each figure in separate lines?

Comment: Hey @blues5, are you sure you need actual captions? Wouldn't 4 simple lines of text be sufficient?

Comment: @sheß, this four captions would be four model ouputs. i've posted the code that i'm using currently but it's too spacious.

Comment: @Zarko. i've posted the code. but i need to reframe that in a grid to reduce space.

Comment: I made an edit to your post to fix your figure and add code highlighting. Always try to do this yourself, it will increase your chances of getting help.

What you mean by "model" is probably context specific, but it sounds very much to me like what you're looking for is either a key for your figure or simply to write text next to it.

Comment: please extend your code fragment to complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. in preamble of this document should be loaded only relevant packages needed for document compilation.

Comment: @blues Excuse me, but I have read now. When I have seen your picture I have undertsood your question :-(. Sorry. I'm pretty sure that the greats **leandris** and **Zarko** have found the right solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

**edit:**  still guessing ... but now images are in array of 2 x 2 images:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure*}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf, 
                  justification=raggedright,
                  skip=0.5ex, singlelinecheck=false}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{4}{X} @{}}
\includegraphics[valign=T]{example-image-duck}
    &   \caption{The first caption}
        \caption{The second caption}
        \caption{The third caption}
        \caption{The fourth caption}
        &   \includegraphics[valign=T]{example-image-duck}
                &   \caption{The first caption}
                    \caption{The second caption}
                    \caption{The third caption}
                    \caption{The fourth caption}    \\
\includegraphics[valign=T]{example-image-duck}
    &   \caption{The first caption}
        \caption{The second caption}
        \caption{The third caption}
        \caption{The fourth caption}
        &   \includegraphics[valign=T]{example-image-duck}
                &   \caption{The first caption}
                    \caption{The second caption}
                    \caption{The third caption}
                    \caption{The fourth caption}    
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to me is a very correct answer to the literal question the OP asked, but I doubt that this is actually what the OP wants to do. @blues5, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: posted the new code. but it still looks terrible. inserting a minipage within minipage might take care for the alignment i guess

Comment: @blues, your mwe contain errors (missed packages, etc}. anyway, see, if my edited answer is close to what you like to have.

Comment: @sheß, you are right. meanwhile i correct my answer (according to quite unclear sketch in question}. i still woundering about four captions per images ... mabe op looks for `\caption*{< some description>}` or simple list of options. who knows. let us wait what will op say.

Comment: sorry for the poor description.  there would be four system output corresponding to each image. say for image 1, i have the original description and three system output.

Comment: also the image is pretty misleading.i'm not able to delete it myself

Comment: @Zarko, thanks so much for helping out so far. the 2*2 grid did work but i'm not able to disable figure1, figure 2,..labels

Comment: @blues, as i mentioned in comment to *sheß*, instead `\caption{...}` use `\caption*{...}`. however, your document example has `\caption{...}`. temporary i'm without my crystal ball, it went to the carnival ... :-), so i can only guess what you like to have.

Comment: @Zarko, perfect!  what a great learning platform is this!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The above shown output is achieved using nested tables as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}Xp{2cm}X}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{lL{3cm}}
Original:&  Two people walking on the beach.\\ 
Model21:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model2:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model23:&  Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
\end{tabular} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{lL{3cm}}
Original:&  Two people walking on the beach.\\ 
Model21:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model2:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model23:&  Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
\end{tabular}\\
\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{lL{3cm}}
Original:&  Two people walking on the beach.\\ 
Model21:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model2:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model23:&  Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
\end{tabular} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{lL{3cm}}
Original:&  Two people walking on the beach.\\ 
Model21:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model2:&   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
Model23:&  Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Here is a variant using the `description` environment instead of nested tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}Zp{2cm}Z}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\begin{description}
\item[Original]  Two people walking on the beach.
\item[Model21]   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. 
\item[Model2]   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. 
\item[Model23]  Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. 
\end{description} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\begin{description}
\item[Original]  Two people walking on the beach.
\item[Model21]   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. 
\item[Model2]   Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. 
\item[Model23]  Zwei Personen gehen am Strand. 
\end{description}
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```